# Unable to cast object of type 'PX.Objects.IN.INLotSerialStatus' to type 'PX.Objects.IN.Overrides.INDocumentRelease.LotSerialStatus'. in acumatica

Tags: acumatica

While multiple lot Allocation I am getting error:

---

```
  Unable to cast object of type 'PX.Objects.IN.INLotSerialStatus'
  to type 'PX.Objects.IN.Overrides.INDocumentRelease.LotSerialStatus'.
```

Answer (score 0):

First unpublish all customization and try to reproduce the issue.
If it goes away re-publish customizations one by one until you find the one causing the cast error.

Review the code of the customization for all references to INLotSerialStatus and LotSerialStatus. Also look at Acumatica traces to find more details about the error.

A LotSerialStatus object is also a INLotSerialStatus because LotSerialStatus inherits from INLotSerialStatus. This is a valid assignment.

The inverse is not true, maybe there is an invalid assignment for which no cast is possible in the source code of the customization:

[image]

Comment: Thank you ... I have check with all this option but in my case i am not assigning any LotSerialStatus  value.  I am able to allocate one row with Lot/Serial No. but when i try to allocate more then one row with Lot/Serial No that time i got this error. Please suggest how can i solve this error.

Comment: Unpublish customization first to locate the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to have the view of original INLotSerialStatus table in your graph:

```
public PXSelect<INLotSerialStatus> OrigLotSerialStatus;
```

It's not important to use it.